# What is an efficient way to find the minimum sum of multiple dictionary values, given keys of mutually exclusive integers?

Tags: python, performance, combinations

I have a dictionary, the keys of which consist of all len(4) combinations of the integers 0 to *n*, with all values being floats (representing a cost that was computed by another function).

e.g.:

```
cost_dict = {(0,1,2,3): 6.23, (0,1,2,4): 7.89,
            ...
            (14,15,16,17): 2.57}
```

I would like to efficiently find *m* mutually exclusive keys (that is, where the keys do not share any of their integers) whose values sum to the lowest number (thus, finding the lowest overall cost). That is, I don't just want the *m* minimum values of the dictionary, I want *m* mutually exclusive values that sum to the lowest value. (Or failing the absolute minimum, I wouldn't mind something efficient that comes pretty close).

So in the above example, for *m* = 3, maybe:

```
cost_dict[(0,3,5,11)]
>1.1 
cost_dict[(2,6,7,13)]
>0.24
cost_dict[(4,10,14,15)]
>3.91
```

... could be the keys whose values sum to the lowest possible value, of all mutually exclusively keys in this dictionary.

It may be possible that the smallest three values in the dict were something like:

```
cost_dict[(0,3,7,13)]
>0.5
cost_dict[(2,6,7,13)]
>0.24
cost_dict[(4,6,14,15)]
>0.8
```

But given the integers in these keys are *not* mutually exclusive, this would not be correct.

---

Is it possible to do better than O(n**m) time? That is, I could sum every item against every other item whose key is disjoint with the first (this would need the keys to be frozensets instead of tuples) for *m* levels. This is rather slow given the dictionary's length can be up to 10,000.

Something that seems to have helped me with an earlier version of this problem is creating a list of all possible combinations of keys, which is time-intensive, but potentially more efficient given that I will need to be finding the minimum cost numerous times.

Comment: All of your example keys are increasing, is that indicative of your problem or no? Is (4, 3, 2, 1) a valid key? Are the keys ordered, e.g. is (1, 2, 3, 4) a different key than (4, 3, 2, 1)? By "mutually exclusive keys" do you mean that the key tuples cannot share any values? Do you have the option of using a different data structure for the costs if necessary?

Comment: If the dictionary consists of all len(4) combinations and since keys in dictionaries must be unique, your concern about "mutually exclusive values" seems like a given. Also you may not need to create a separate list of all possible keys, because they're the `keys()` of that dictionary.

Comment: @Alexander Reynolds - The order of the integers in the keys is irrelevant. So there's only one key for the integers 1-4. I've made it (1,2,3,4), but it could be something else (like a frozenset) if that would help. Thanks for pointing out the syntax, fixed. I'm open to using a different data structure if that would be more efficient.

Comment: @martineau - What I mean by "mutually exclusive" is that the keys share no integers. Thus (1,2,3,4) and (1,2,4,5) would be False, but (1,2,3,4) and (5,6,7,8) would be True.

Comment: What is `n`? Are the values densely packed?

Comment: @AustinHastings - *n* would vary between ~12 and ~24. It's for all unordered combos ((of len(4)) of the integers (0,*n*).

Comment: You could use integer bitsets in lieu of frozen sets or whatever, and get numpy to do some of your work for you in generating lists of all possible combinations of keys.

Comment: Perhaps it is problem of finding [independent set in the graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) of size m with the smallest weight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried solving this problem three different ways- an optimized brute force, a dynamic programming approach, and a greedy algorithm. The first two could not handle inputs for `n > 17`, but generated optimal solutions, so I could use them to verify the average performance of the greedy method. I'll start first with the dynamic programming approach, and then describe the greedy one.

#### Dynamic Programming

First, note that we can if we determine that `(1, 2, 3, 4)` and `(5, 6, 7, 8)` sum to a smaller value than `(3, 4, 5, 6)` and `(1, 2, 7, 8)`, then your optimal solution absolutely cannot contain both `(3, 4, 5, 6)` and `(1, 2, 7, 8)`- because you could swap them out for the former, and have a smaller sum. Extending this logic, there will be one optimal combination of `(a, b, c, d)` and `(e, f, g, h)` that results in the minimal sum from all combinations of `x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7`, and so we can rule out all of the others.

Using this knowledge, we can be a dictionary mapping of all `x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7` combinations from the set `[0, n)`, to their minimal sums, by brute forcing the sums of all combinations of `x0, x1, x2, x3`. Then, we can use these mappings to repeat the process for `x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11` from `x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7` and `x0, x1, x2, x3` pairs. We repeat this process until we obtain all minimal sums for `x0, x1 ... x_(4*m-1)`, which we then iterate over to find the minimal sum.

```
def dp_solve(const_dict, n, m):

    lookup = {comb:(comb,) for comb in const_dict.keys()}

    keys = set(range(n))
    for size in range(8, 4 * m + 1, 4):
        for key_total in combinations(keys, size):
            key_set = set(key_total)
            min_keys = (key_total[:4], key_total[4:])
            min_val = const_dict[min_keys[0]] + const_dict[min_keys[1]]

            key1, key2 = min(zip(combinations(key_total, 4), reversed(list(combinations(key_total, size - 4)))), key=lambda x:const_dict[x[0]]+const_dict[x[1]])

            k = tuple(sorted(x for x in key1 + key2))
            const_dict[k] = const_dict[key1] + const_dict[key2]
            lookup[k] = lookup[key1] + lookup[key2]

    key, val = min(((key, val) for key, val in const_dict.items() if len(key) == 4 * m), key=lambda x: x[1])
    return lookup[key], val
```

Admittedly this implementation is pretty gnarly, because I kept micro-optimizing piece after piece hoping to make it fast enough without having to switch to a greedy approach.

#### Greedy

This is probably the one you care about, since it handles fairly large inputs quickly, and is quite accurate.

Start by constructing a list for partial sums, and begin iterating over your elements in your dictionary by increasing value. For each element, find all partial sums that don't create any collisions with their keys and "combine" them into a new partial sum, and append to the list. In doing so, you build a list of minimal partial sums that can be created from the smallest `k` values in your dictionary. To speed this all up, I use hash sets to quickly check which partial sums contain pairs of the same key.

In the "fast" greedy approach, you would abort the moment you find a partial sum that has a key length of `4 * m` (or equivalently, of `m` 4-tuples). This usually nets fairly good results in my experience, but I wanted to add some logic to make it more accurate if need be. To do so, I add two factors-

- `extra_runs` - which dictates how many extra iterations to search for better solutions before breaking
- `check_factor` - which specifies a multiple of current search "depth" to scan forward for a *single* new integer that creates a better solution with the current state. This is different from the above in that it does not "preserve" each new integer checked- it only does a quick sum to see if it creates a new min. This makes it significantly faster, at the cost that the other `m - 1` 4-tuples must already exist in one of the partial sums.

Combined, these checks seem to always find the true minimal sum, at the cost of about 5x longer runtime (still quite fast though). To disable them, just pass `0` for both factors.

```
def greedy_solve(const_dict, n, m, extra_runs=10, check_factor=2):
    pairs = sorted(const_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])

    lookup = [set([]) for _ in range(n)]
    nset = set([])

    min_sums = []
    min_key, min_val = None, None
    for i, (pkey, pval) in enumerate(pairs):
        valid = set(nset)
        for x in pkey:
            valid -= lookup[x]
            lookup[x].add(len(min_sums))
        
        nset.add(len(min_sums))
        min_sums.append(((pkey,), pval))

        for x in pkey:
            lookup[x].update(range(len(min_sums), len(min_sums) + len(valid)))
        for idx in valid:
            comb, val = min_sums[idx]
            for key in comb:
                for x in key:
                    lookup[x].add(len(min_sums))
            nset.add(len(min_sums))
            min_sums.append((comb + (pkey,), val + pval))
            if len(comb) == m - 1 and (not min_key or min_val > val + pval):
                min_key, min_val = min_sums[-1]
        
        if min_key:
            if not extra_runs: break
            extra_runs -= 1

    for pkey, pval in pairs[:int(check_factor*i)]:
        valid = set(nset)
        for x in pkey:
            valid -= lookup[x]
        
        for idx in valid:
            comb, val = min_sums[idx]
            if len(comb) < m - 1:
                nset.remove(idx)
            elif min_val > val + pval:
                min_key, min_val = comb + (pkey,), val + pval
    return min_key, min_val
```

I tested this for `n < 36` and `m < 9`, and it seemed to run fairly fast (couple of seconds to complete at worst). I'd imagine it should work for your case `12 <= n <= 24` pretty quickly.

Comment: I can verify that this produces the same output as my current brute-force every single combination method. So thanks!

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a good idea of how to add a parameter to greedy-solve: "The keys must include the integers in set {x}"? For instance, you may want the returned keys to include both 4 and 7 (though not necessarily in the same key). (I tried a hackish approach of simply adding very high negative costs to all instances of values whose keys contain integers that need to be included, but this makes the algorithm run vastly slower for some reason).

Comment: You could add another condition to both if statements for assigning `min_key, min_val`, that checks that `all(x in tuple(k for c in comb for k in c) + pkey for x in required_keys)` or something like that.

Comment: This appears to work for the first if statement, however, not for the second (when check_factor >0). The big issue though is time - for relatively high lengths of required keys (e.g. 10 with n=3 and m=22), even with no check factors, it could take a minute or more to return an answer.

Comment: @Plato'sCave what exactly do you mean by doesn't work? As in it returns an invalid answer, one that doesn't contain the required integers, or times out? I can take a sec to see if I can find any optimizations, but if the `all(...)` isn't working then that will need tweaked first.

Comment: It can return answers that don't contain the required integers.

Comment: @Plato'sCave That's odd, I really don't understand how that's possible. Try wrapping the assignments on lines 28 and 44 in separate `if all(...)`s to make sure operator precedence or something isn't coming into play.

Comment: Regarding optimization, you could possibly lower `extra_runs` a tiny bit, drop the stipulation that `if all(...)` in the first occurrence (the one that currently works), and then remove everything `check_factor` related- just search until one solution is found, and then break out of the loop. It isn't guaranteed to find a solution then, but rather than bloat the intermediate arrays (causing the runtime to blow up) to assert all the necessary pairs have been searched, stop short and hope that we've encountered all but one key, and that the cheap final check finds it.

Comment: If you're dropping "if all', where is it that we ensure that all required keys are contained? (Also, I find that even if extra runs and check factors are both set to 0, then it can still take a long time, e.g. ~70 seconds for required keys=len(10), n=18, m=3).

Comment: @Plato'sCave only drop the first `if all()`; the second one stays, and if you remove the `check_factor` bit, it will not terminate until a solution is found (because of the second `if all()`.  And regarding execution time- it can be sped up by clipping the increasingly expensive pruning between finding the n-1th and nth keys, if we can guess when we've likely encountered the n-1th key. That's what these changes will do- you can tweak `extra_runs` to guess when we've found the other n-1 keys and stop- at the cost of potentially guessing short.

Comment: Actually, there is one other thing you could try (non-optimal, but fast). Break the problem in half- solve for a handful of minimal cost keys that fill the required set (rounded to nearest 4), and then solve the normal problem for `set(0..n) - set(key_from_each_solution)`. If need be, you could even add pseudo required-keys (at the cost of less accuracy) which would allow you to use the original problems code unmodified.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188235/discussion-between-platos-cave-and-dillon-davis).